# Ubuntu won't wake up from suspend: probably faulty module

Tags: kernel, suspend, power-management, wakeup

After a recent kernel update, Ubuntu stopped waking up from suspend. It just freezes, the screen is black and no reaction to keys comes.

I'm not using the `nouveau` driver. My display manager is `GDM3`.

Doing `journalctl -t systemd-sleep -n 20` gives:

```
Feb 12 20:58:48 xx-G750JW systemd-sleep[9743]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module 8822bu not found.
Feb 12 20:58:48 xx-G750JW systemd-sleep[9746]: modprobe: FATAL: Module 8822bu not found in
directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-99-generic
```

Yet, say, `8822bu` is not found in the system.

Any hints on where to look for bugs and how to fix them?

Comment: In my experience the GPU (like NVIDIA) is usually,but not always the culprit. The fatal module seems to be a [USB Wifi driver](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver) Can you remove that and try again?

Comment: @kanehekili I can't remove it, it's not even listed in `dkms`. It's not there, I don't know why the system is trying to reach out for it while waking up